# opendj-core 6.5.0 maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, directory, opendj

On OpenDJ 2.6.4, i’m using the dependency “opendj-ldap-sdk” in order to use the
following classes:

- org.forgerock.opendj.asn1.ASN1;
- org.forgerock.opendj.asn1.ASN1Writer;
- org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ByteStringBuilder;

I checked that the same classes exist on *Directory Services 6.5* on *lib\opendj-core.jar* but i cannot find the maven dependency to use it (in a context of migration from OpenDJ 2.6.4 to Directory Services 6.5).
I’ve found this dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codice.org.forgerock.opendj</groupId>
<artifactId>opendj-core</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0.ALPHA1</version>
</dependency>
```

but the version doesn’t match..

Where can I find the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

You can unzip `DS-6.5.0.zip` and then add the `<systemPath>` element to your maven dependency. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies .

For a more robust mechanism, if you intend to use *Directory Services 6.5* in production, then I would recommend that you contact your ForgeRock support. They will explain to you how to compile your plugin(s) against this version.